# Typescript annotation question: arrays with key values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Does anyone know why this happens according to VSCode?

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

let grid: [key: number, value: [key: number, value: Point]];

// ...

// Gives an object of type  number | [key: number, value: Point]
var col = grid[-5];
// Gives an object of type  number | Point
var pnt = (col as [key: number, value: Point])[-2];
```

Could anyone explain please?

I want them to not have the `number |`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
let grid: [key: number, value: [key: number, value: Point]];
```

declares a tuple type: an array with 2 members, where the first is of type `number`, and the second is another tuple, eg:

```
[3, [4, somePoint]]
```

Use an object instead of an array, so that `grid[someNum]` gives you a column:

```
let grid: {
    [key: number]: {
        [key: number]: Point;
    };
}
```

You also might consider using a Map instead of dynamic property names (Maps are better designed for this sort of thing, and you'll occasionally run into issues with those sorts of dynamic property names in TypeScript)

```
type Col = Map<number, Point>;
const grid = new Map<number, Col>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `let grid` is being initialized here:

```
let grid: [key: number, value: [key: number, value: Point]];
```

Here 'key' is being set to a number. If you don't want it to return this part, you need to remove the `key: number` part of the code